# NFSv4 file ownerships, nfsidmap name not found in domain

Tags: domain, nfs, nfs4

I have an nfsv4 server and client (both RedHat 6) configured with the method set to nsswitch, and the same domain set on both client and server in /etc/idmapd.conf.  On the client I get nobody:nobody ownerships and the following message in /var/log/messages for each user:

```
nfsidmap[632]: nss_getpwnam: name 'bob' not found in domain 'mydomain'
```

Now the 'bob' account is not on the client system but on the server only, so the client must be getting it through rpcidmapd to show in the log message.

How do I get the proper ownerships to show up and not default back to nobody:nobody?

Answer (score 1):

you need user 'bob' on the client and server. You may enforce server to send numeric IDs by

```
# echo "options nfs nfs4_disable_idmapping=1" >> /etc/modprobe.d/nfs.conf
```